# Import within Angular library causes TypeScript error "File is not under rootDir"

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a Angular project with the following structure:

```
projects/
   projectA/
   projectB/
   library/
shared/
```

`shared` contains resources shared across Angular applications *and* non-Angular consumers (e.g. Electron).

If I import anything from `shared` within `projectA` everything works fine - but as soon as I import from `shared` within `library` I get the following error:

> error TS6059: File ... is not under 'rootDir'

I tried to set `rootDir` (and `rootDirs`) within the `tsconfig` of `library` but neither did work.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Re-structured the project. The `rootDir` option is hard-coded within the CLI, hence is (or was, don't know about the current status) pretty unsolvable otherwise.

Comment: yeah, i had to go through each and every component to look for barrel imports and was able to build the library after removing barrel imports. Thanks for the reply.